# Problem with printing the bibliography on my beamer presentation

Tags: latex, styles, beamer, bibliography

I can't find why my bibliography in my beamer does not show a numeric citation, but this paper symbol...
Any help?
Thanks
[biblio photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhoiF.png)

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, citestyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib} %Imports bibliography file


\section{Bibliographie}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Bibliographie}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
%\bibliography{ref}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Is your tex distribution up to date?

Answer (score 4):

About a year ago I made some changes to automatically show the biblabel for numeric biblatex styles ([21cf3d](https://github.com/samcarter/beamer/commit/2a81ef0c0172a4ba7ee11676a177c7f6fd21cf3d)). So with beamer v3.58 or newer  you don't have to do anything:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, citestyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\begin{document}
\section{Bibliographie}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Bibliographie}
\nocite{knuth:ct}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you have an older version, you need to switch this on manually:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, citestyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\begin{document}
\section{Bibliographie}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Bibliographie}
\nocite{knuth:ct}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]